# Intro to C++: Sorting code

Tags: c++

I am studying for a final exam that is scheduled today. My question is, what does the do-while(swap) statement do here? Is swap set to "true" by default?

My understanding of this code is that it iterates at least once for each pass of the sort. The inner for loop carries the crucial code and does all the swaps in the pass. For example, array[count] is copied into temp, array[count+1] is copied into array[count] and array[count] is copied into array[count+1]. If the two elements are swapped, the bool swap is set to true. The outer loop keeps iterating until it finds the swap flag false.

```
void sortArray(int array[], int size)
{
   int size;
   bool swap;

do
{
   swap = false;
   for(int count = 0; count < (size -1); count++)
   {
      if(array[count] > array[count+1])
      {
         temp = array[count];
         array[count] = array[count+1];
         array[count+1] = temp;
         swap = true;
       }
    }
  }while(swap);
 }
```

Comment: Why does it matter what `swap` is initially? The very next statement sets it to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Swap` is used to check if algorithm is still sorting or not. If `swap` is false, it means that array is already sorted and algorithm can be finished.

By default (in the beginning of each iteration of `do-while` loop) `swap` is set to false and it's change to `true` only if swap was made (it means that array elements weren't in correct order).

Answer (score 1):

`Swap` variable is used to determine end of algorithm.If array is sorted, no swap occurs and `swap` variable will be false, hence end of sorting.

Default value of `swap` variable is undefined, but it doesnt matter, since you assign it as false in each iteration before processing array from beggining

Answer (score 0):

while-do is used to execute for loop until no elements in the array should be swapped. If no swaps occurred during the for loop, than all elements are sorted. But, if during the execution of the inner loop two elements were swapped, the array is scanned again to check if the result array is sorted.